# Installing latest protocol decoders in Sigrok PulseView

Tags: network-protocols

I can see that the Futaba SBus decoder is supported by the community but can't see a way to install it.

I have tried copying the files into a new folder alongside the existing decoder files but the decoder is not recognised in the list in PulseView or as a stacked decoder.

I must be missing something simple but would appreciate help to get past this issue.